# GenericObjectPool Returned object not currently part of this pool

Tags: java, pool, apache-commons-pool

I have created a pool of objects that I need to reuse. Every time I try to return the object I get an error of: "Returned object not currently part of this pool"

I have override the both the equals and hashcode methods but that does not help.

I set the pool up using this code:

```
GenericObjectPoolConfig config = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();
config.setMaxIdle(10);
config.setMaxTotal(10);
config.setTestOnBorrow(true);
config.setTestOnReturn(true); 
ImageDownloaderPool.POOL= new ImageDownloaderPool<String, String>(new ImageDownloaderFactory<String, String>(), config);
```

Here is how I am overriding equals and hashCode:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
   if (this == o) return true;
   if (!(o instanceof ImageDownloader)) return false;
   ImageDownloader<String, String> that = (ImageDownloader<String, String>) o;
   if (id != null ? !id.equals(that.id) : that.id != null) return false;
   return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
}
```

I call returnObject on the Pool like this:

```
 finally { 
   if (dl != null) { 
      try {
         ImageDownloaderPool.getPOOL().returnObject(dl);
      } 
      catch (Exception e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
      }
```

I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Returned object not currently part of this pool
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.returnObject(GenericObjectPool.java:524)
>   com.ifmrestoration.webscraper.CorrigoScraperPool.returnObject(CorrigoScraperPool.java:45)
>   com.ifmrestoration.webscraper.ImageDownloader.saveImageFromAWSurl(ImageDownloader.java:164)
>   com.ifmrestoration.webscraper.ImageDownloaderServlet.doPost(ImageDownloaderServlet.java:49)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848)
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1772)
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.ParseBlobUploadHandler.handle(ParseBlobUploadHandler.java:119)
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1182)
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.doHandle(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:187)
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:293)
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:539)
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:333)
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnection.handle(RpcConnection.java:213)
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnector.serviceRequest(RpcConnector.java:81)
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:722)
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:685)
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:655)
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:847)
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:270)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Where does the exception occur? Please share all relevant code, the full stack trace and create a [MRE].

Comment: How are you setting `dl` ?  Are you using `borrow()`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are instantiating your pool with two classes i assume you are extending

```
org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool
```

In that case, you should use:

```
pool.returnObject("yourkey", yourobject);
```

AFAIK override is not needed.